# Unsure how to format Multipart form data for Open AI STT API call on ESP32

Tags: post, multipartform-data, esp32, openai-api, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to use an ESP32 with the Open AI APIs for a university project, some are working well, however I'm struggling with a speech to text API.

The API expects some headers and a multipart form data with some strings and an audio file. I cant figure out how I add the audio file into the multipart form data. I've tried asking chat GPT itself for the code but its garbage, how do I pass this audio file to the API?

The code below is essentially creating a payload and adding the file part way through, but I dont think/understand if it should just be appended to the payload which is a string or if it needs to be handled differently.

The API reference is;

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription

file Required
The audio file object (not file name) to transcribe, in one of these formats: flac, mp3, mp4, mpeg, mpga, m4a, ogg, wav, or webm.

```
void STTAPI() {
  HTTPClient http;

  const char *model = "whisper-1";
  const char *filename = "/Test/CapitalofEngland.wav";

  // Open the WAV file on the SD card
  File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_READ);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Error opening WAV file");
    return;
  }

  size_t fileSize = file.size();

  // Begin the HTTP request
  http.begin("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions");

  // Set headers
  String authorizationHeader = "Bearer ";
  authorizationHeader += API_Key;
  http.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader.c_str());
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundarystring");

  // Create the multipart/form-data payload
  String boundary = "boundarystring";
  String payload = "--";
  payload += boundary;
  payload += "\r\n";
  payload += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"";
  payload += filename;
  payload += "\"\r\n";
  payload += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

  // Read binary data into the dynamically allocated buffer
  const int bufferSize = fileSize;
  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(bufferSize);
  if (!buffer) {
    Serial.println("Memory allocation failed");
    file.close();
    return;
  }

  int bytesRead;

  while ((bytesRead = file.read(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(buffer), bufferSize)) > 0) {
    payload += String(buffer, bytesRead);
  }

  payload += "\r\n";
  payload += "--";
  payload += boundary;
  payload += "\r\n";
  payload += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"model\"\r\n\r\n";
  payload += model;
  payload += "\r\n";
  payload += "--";
  payload += boundary;
  payload += "--\r\n";

  // Send the payload
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);

  // Check for a successful response
  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

    // Print the response payload
    String responsePayload = http.getString();
    Serial.println("Response payload: " + responsePayload);
  } else {
    Serial.print("HTTP Request failed, error: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }

  // Free the dynamically allocated buffer
  free(buffer);

  // End the request
  http.end();
  file.close();
```

Tried the code above, expected it to return a text string from the API with a transcription, however using some code it says the audio file is not in the correct format.

Comment: None of the tags that you tagged are relevant to your question. How to format multipart form data is a question about HTTP, has nothing to do with Arduino, ESP32 or even OpenAI. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712083) probably provides the links that you need to learn from it, or simply google "http multipart".

Comment: The article helped but still doesnt help with the context above.

Comment: Okay, I re-read your post, your question is actually not "how to format Multipart form data" as your title, but "how to upload audio file as part of HTTP Multipart request". Your code does not actually read the file from SD and send it as a multipart content. Please take a look at a similar question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950275).